# Bootstrap 4 - How To Properly Center a Div (Form)?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, pug

I'm just getting started into using Bootstrap, and am having a bit of trouble getting a form to display in the center of the page. So far, what I have done is use CSS-styling to make sure that both html and body tags are at 100% height. Then I have two divs: the outer div uses the entire height of the page, and uses "justify-content-center." The inner div uses "align-items-center." With this, I have managed to get the form to display in the center. However, I'm left with this whitespace that stretches on the top and bottom of the form.

This is somewhat of a vague question, but is there a way for me to to either remove that whitespace (as in like shrink the container or something), or perhaps go about centering a div a different way?

I am using jade/pug for my view template engine. Here is the source code:

```
block content
  div(class="row h-100 justify-content-center")
    div(class="d-flex align-items-center shadow-lg p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded")
      div
        h3(class="text-center") Submit Your Attendance
        form
          div(class="form-group")
            label(for="firstname") First Name
            input(class="form-control", type="text", id="firstname", placeholder="John", name="firstname")
          div(class="form-group")
            label(for="lastname") Last Name
            input(class="form-control", type="text", id="lastname", placeholder="Doe", name="lastname")
          div(class="form-group")
            label(for="email") Email Address
            input(class="form-control", type="text", id="email", placeholder="johndoe@email.com", name="email")
          div(class="text-center")
            button(class="btn btn-primary", type="submit") Submit
```

Here is the layout.jade that it inherits from:

```
doctype html
html(style="height:100%")
  head
    title= title
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css')
    script(src="/../node_modules/jquery/jquery.min.js")
    script(src="/../node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js")
    script(src="/../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js")
  body(style="height:100%;background-image:url(../public/images/index-background.jpg);")
    block content
```

And here is what the page looks like:
[screenshot of the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nX7HE.png)

Any suggestions would be appreciated, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `align-items-center` class along with row class.

```
block content
  div(class="row h-100 justify-content-center align-items-center") /*add align-items-center here*/
    div(class="d-flex flex-column align-items-center shadow-lg p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded")
      div
        h3(class="text-center") Submit Your Attendance
        form
          div(class="form-group")
            label(for="firstname") First Name
            input(class="form-control", type="text", id="firstname", placeholder="John", name="firstname")
          div(class="form-group")
            label(for="lastname") Last Name
            input(class="form-control", type="text", id="lastname", placeholder="Doe", name="lastname")
          div(class="form-group")
            label(for="email") Email Address
            input(class="form-control", type="text", id="email", placeholder="johndoe@email.com", name="email")
          div(class="text-center")
            button(class="btn btn-primary", type="submit") Submit
```

just I converted pug html into normal its working fine.

DEMO:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" style="height:100%;">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset=" utf-8 ">
  <meta name="viewport " content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1 ">
  <link rel="stylesheet " href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css ">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js "></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js "></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js "></script>
</head>

<body style="height:100% ">
  <div class="row h-100 justify-content-center align-items-center ">

    <div class="d-flex flex-column align-items-center shadow-lg p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded ">
      <h3 class="text-center ">Submit Your Attendance form
      </h3>
      <form>
        <div class="form-group ">
          <label for="firstname ">First Name</label>
          <input class="form-control " type="text " id="firstname " , placeholder="John " name="firstname "><br>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group ">
          <label for="lastname ">Last Name</label>
          <input class="form-control " type="text " id="firstname " , placeholder="John " name="firstname "><br> </div>
        <div class="form-group ">
          <label for="email ">Email</label>
          <input class="form-control " type="text " id="email " placeholder="johndoe@email.com " name="email "><br>
        </div>
        <div class="text-center ">
          <button type="submit " value="Submit ">submit</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you very much! Gave an upvote for this answer, but site says that it does not display because I have less than 15 reputation.

Comment: @HH-chan u need at least 15 reputations to upvote u can upvotes once u got 15 reputation